# Powershell don't give output after running exe

Tags: azure, powershell

I have following line of code in my script which I'm running from my management laptop to servers. Code is inside of scriptblock

```
# If a proxy server is needed, execute these commands with the proxy URL and port.
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("https_proxy","http://{proxy-url}:{proxy-port}","Machine")
$env:https_proxy = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("https_proxy","Machine")
# For the changes to take effect, the agent service needs to be restarted after the proxy environment variable is set.
Restart-Service -Name himds

    # Install the package
    msiexec /i c:\temp\AzureConnectedMachineAgent.msi /l*v c:\temp\installationlog.txt /qn | Out-String
    
    # The agent service needs to be restarted after the proxy environment variable is set in order for the changes to take effect.
    Restart-Service -Name himds
    
   
    # Run connect command
    &  "$env:ProgramFiles\AzureConnectedMachineAgent\azcmagent.exe" >> $logfolder\$logfile connect  `
    --service-principal-id $appId `
    --service-principal-secret $password `
    --resource-group $resourceGroup `
    --tenant-id $tenantId `
    --location $location `
    --subscription-id $subscriptionId
```

problem is that I don't get any output of that in my Powershell (on my management laptop) screen when running the script. I know that running that exe gives output. Output should look something like when running on local machine or when using  following command end of script

> $output | Out-File -FilePath .\AzureArc.txt -append

[image]

Tried also Start-Transcript and Stop-Transcript but did not display logs neiher.

Tips what should I try so that I would get logs to show on my screen while script i

EDIT: Added pretty much whole code from scriptblock. Added also >> $logfolder$logfile to end of azcmagent.exe which made that I was able to collect logs to file but were not able do get them to show on Powershell while running script.

Comment: "Code is inside of scriptblock" please either post the full context, or create a minimal example with which this behavior can be reproduced.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I have now pretty much shared whole script which is inside of script block.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write output to screen you would need to add some [write-output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-7.1), [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7.1) or [verbose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-verbose?view=powershell-7.1) Code is inside the scriptblock/azcmagent.exe.
Since you have not pasted your code it would be hard to specify where to add this. Here re some examples>>

eg.

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | Where-Object HasPicture -eq $true -Verbose
```

or

```
$data = "My data to output"
Write-Host $data -ForegroundColor Green
```